# LINQ ternary result of binary list

Tags: c#, linq, boolean, iteration, ternary

Assume I have a list of binary parameters (in reality it is a list of checkboxes' `IsChecked.Value` property). I'm trying to get the `bool?` (ternary) result that:

- is `true` if **all** the elements in the list are `true`
- is `false` if **all** the elements in the list are `false`
- is `null` in all other cases, thus there are both `true` and `false` elements in the list or the list is empty

Until now I came up with the solution that requires iterating over the list twice (checking whether all elements are either `true` or `false`) and then comparing the results to deciding whether to return `true`, `false` or `null`.

This is my code:

```cs
bool checkTrue = myListOfBooleans.All(l => l);
bool checkFalse = myListOfBooleans.All(l => !l);
bool? result = (!checkTrue && !checkFalse) ? null : (bool?)checkTrue;
```

How can I achieve it in only one iteration over the list?

Comment: `myListOfBooleans.Cast<bool?>().Aggregate((c, a) => c == a ? a : null)`  Note it throws if the list is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that by using `Aggegrate`

```
public bool? AllSameValue(List<bool> myListOfBooleans)
{
    if(myListOfBooleans.Count == 0) return null; // or whatever value makes sense

    return myListOfBooleans.Cast<bool?>().Aggregate((c, a) => c == a ? a : null);
}
```

That casts your values to `bool?` so that you can then compare them and return the value if that they all match or null if there is a difference.

Of course you could exit early by taking the first one and using `All` to see if the rest match or not.

```
public bool? AllSameValue(List<bool> myListOfBooleans)
{
    if(myListOfBooleans.Count == 0) return null; // or whatever value makes sense

    bool first = myListOfBooleans[0];
    return myListOfBooleans.All(x => x == first ) ? first : null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like this oneliner using aggregate. For the second solution - it is faster as this needs to iterate the whole list only if all elements are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply **count** the `true` values:

```
int c = myListOfBooleans.Count(l => l);
bool? result = c == myListOfBooleans.Count 
               ? (bool?)true 
               : (c == 0 ? (bool?)false : null);
```

Note that this is `true` for an empty list, you may want to tweak that according to your required logic.

---

For a better performance (though I don't think it matters in a UI context) you could write an extension that could even return early if the result is clear (instead of iterating through the whole list):

```
public static bool? AllOrNothing(this IEnumerable<bool> list)
{
    if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));

    using(var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) 
            return null; // or true or false, what you need for an empty list

        bool? current = enumerator.Current;
        while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            if (current != enumerator.Current) return null;
        return current;
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
bool? result = myListOfBooleans.AllOrNothing();
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this extension approach - it comes handy if there are more of those ternary (three state) checkboxes where the state is determined by the combination of the "slave" checkboxes. At the moment I have only one of those, so the simpler solution the better.