# Select all group items by checking group header checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have implemented custom ComboBox control which collection items have groups. There are group headers and following group items. It looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" x:Key="ComboBoxNoGroupHeaderStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" x:Key="ComboBoxDefaultGroupHeaderStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ppstd:ComboBoxHeaderStyleSelector x:Key="ComboBoxGroupStyleSelector"
                                   ComboBoxNoGroupHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxNoGroupHeaderStyle}"
                                   ComboBoxDefaultGroupHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxDefaultGroupHeaderStyle}"/>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxGroupHeaderTemplate">
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
              FontWeight="Bold">
    //IsChecked={Binding IsHeaderCheckboxChecked}" tried this but DataContext is type of GroupItem, which has eg. Name property among others
    </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>

<ComboBox >
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle >
        <GroupStyle
            ContainerStyleSelector = "{StaticResource ComboBoxGroupStyleSelector}"
            HeaderTemplate = "{StaticResource ComboBoxGroupHeaderTemplate}" / >
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle >
</ComboBox>
```

It looks great, but it misses one functionality: selecting group items by checking group header checkbox. I tought it would be done by adding `IsChecked` property to `ComboBoxGroupHeaderTemplate` DataTemplate, and then implement this functionality when this property is set, but it isn't that simple as I imagined. To be honest, I'm stucked at this moment and have no ideas how to go further.

I heard about `Behaviors`, but I've never used that and I don't know this is good way to achieve that.

The question is: Is it possible to achieve that ? If it is, how ? Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest (in my opinion) way to achieve what you're describing is using bindings:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="HeadCheckBox" Content="Header" />
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox1" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=HeadCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox2" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=HeadCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox3" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=HeadCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox4" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=HeadCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Now each checkbox can be checked individually but checking or unchecking the header sets all bound checkboxes at the same time.

The drawback of this solution is that if only part of your checkboxes are checked, it would be nice to see the header as "undefined" (checkboxes have "three-state" option).
I asked a question on how to get the tri-state for the header ([LINQ ternary result of binary list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695722/linq-ternary-result-of-binary-list)). I'm not sure yet how to add it to your solution as even if the "slave" checkbox is not three-state, it takes the state of the master (also undefined state). Perhaps a value converter can help here.